# Can we have MS Dynamic AX 2009 as a source in SSRS report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, dax

Is this possible to have MS Dynamic AX 2009 as a source in SSRS report? How to do that

and we can use SQL query for accessing data for the same source ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "Report data source" to the project.  The connection string property should look like the following:  Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=SSPI

Then add a dataset and use the new report data source as the data source.